# Databinding activity does not update value when property has changed

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

I have an activity that is using `DataBinding`.

In my `onCreate()` I have

```
DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.main_layout);
```

so it makes a network request to get the data and then populates the screen properly using data binding.

The problem is that when I open another activity B, it returns a value that I need to use to update in my original activity.

I am trying to update the value in the `onStart()` the value returned from activity B.

I use to update the model.

```
public void setTitle(String title) {
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.title);
}
```

In my xml I have `android:text=“@{myItem.title}”` but the property does not update.

I am not sure if its because I am trying to update it in the `onStart()` and the activity is not ready to update the data binding properties?

But I have tried to update the values without leaving the activity and it works.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Your setter does not set anything. It only invalidates the bound value. So just store the `title` so that the getter is able to return it correctly.

```
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title; // assuming the member is named title as well
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.title);
}
```